# iPhone hardware serial port access 

Tags: arduino, serial, iphone, ipod

Does anyone know how to access the iPhone's serial port, from a program on the iPod to allow that application to send signals. The idea is that the iPod could be used as the brain for some kind of robot by using the serial port to tell an arduino what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the suggestions need a jail-broken phone. [ucHobby](http://www.uchobby.com/index.php/2009/09/06/iphone-audio-breadboard-adaptor/) has a different approach using the audio jack of the phone or ipod.

Comment: can you sum up what is at your link to some extent as links die but stack exchange lives forever!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like what you want:

http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note is that you cannot use the official External Accessory Framework to communicate with accessories, unless the accessory that you're communicating with has been designed under the Made For iPod, or Works With iPhone programs

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the commands and pin outs of the serial port

- Commands: http://nuxx.net/wiki/Apple_Accessory_Protocol
- Pin outs: [www.pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml](http://www.pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

**Related:** Here is a [tutorial](http://pargon.nl/) on how to boot a Jailbroken iPod 2G using a microcontroller.

Cheers,

Marcus

Answer (score 1):

since OS 3.0 there is an API for the hardware port. might wanna use that,

Comment: Unfortunately you need to be part of the "Made for iPhone" Program to use it!

Cheers, 

Marcus

Comment: well that sucks. do you have an official infopage for that? Maybe another reason to give android a try. there's an andrpid arduino project:
http://web.media.mit.edu/~bonifaz/amarino/

Comment: not only do you have to be signed up for the MFI (Made for iPhone) program, but your hardware has to include an Apple authentication chip -- that's actually the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application [GPS2IP](http://www.capsicumdreams.com/iphone/gps2ip/) that outputs NMEA messages (and gpx and kml tracks) without a jailbroken device.
You need to connect to your iPhone with a IP socket though, so that might be difficult for a very simple project. IP stacks for micros aren't terribly difficult to get for free, these days, though..

Comment: In this case what is the physical connectivity between iPhone and your GPS device ?

Comment: The iPhone uses it's own internal GPS, and outputs various (selectable) messages in NMEA format.  
No external GPS needed.